# How to validate image aspect ratio before uploading in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I need to validate image for aspect ratio (4:3) instead if width (800) and height (600) in Codeigniter.

Here is my code :

```
public function uploadImage() {
        $upload_dir = './media/data/';
        $config['upload_path'] = $upload_dir . "800x600";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png|gif|PNG';
        $config['max_size'] = '0';
        $config['max_width'] = '800';
        $config['min_width'] = '800';
        $config['max_height'] = '600';
        $config['min_height'] = '600';
        $name = time() . '_' . rand(00000000, 99999999);
        $config['file_name'] = $name;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo json_encode($error);
        } else {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $file = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
            $this->ImageResize($file, $upload_dir, $name, $data['upload_data']['file_ext']);
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP will not help wth image dimensions before uploading but you can use javascript to load the image and deduce the dimensions prior to upload.

```
var oImg=new Image();
oImg.src='https://static-secure.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/9/24/1411574454561/03085543-87de-47ab-a4eb-58e7e39d022e-620x372.jpeg'
oImg.onload=function(){
    alert('width:'+oImg.width+' height:'+oImg.height +' ratio:'+(oImg.width/oImg.height));
};
```

second attempt - doesn't involve a remote image so should be ok

```
/* where imgx is the ID of the file input field */
document.getElementById('imgx').onchange=function(event){
    var oImg=new Image();
    for( i=0; i < this.files.length; i++ ){
        oImg.src=URL.createObjectURL( this.files[i] );
        oImg.onload=function(){
            var width=oImg.naturalWidth;
            var height=oImg.naturalHeight;

            alert('width:'+oImg.width+' height:'+oImg.height +' ratio:'+(oImg.width/oImg.height));
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: As per your code i need to upload image firstly and then i have to pass uploaded Image url to `oImg.src` after that it will give the dimension. But i want to validate the aspect radio when image is selected it will be checked before uploading it on server.

Comment: true enough - no real benefit there then - apologies for misleading you in that case.

Answer (score -1):

This code will not work; It's a basic code to upload the image.
If you want to re size during the crop then you can use:

```
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
```

But will not work with your code. You can check the validation before uploading the code.

Comment: I want to validate aspect ratio before uploading the image.

Comment: Please read the question carefully before submitting an answer.